# (Stripe) Does the current_period_end update when payment problems occur?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I'm creating a subscription plan, in PHP and I'm using Stripe as a subscription "manager". I have a trivial question to do: in the Stripe subscription object, there's on parameter called current_period_end. Does anyone know something about its behavior?

I mean, if the payment goes correctly, the parameter is updated to the next date in UNIX timestamp. But if the payment goes wrong, does it update? I'm asking and not directly trying because the minimum delay between subscription payments is one day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even if the open invoice's payment fails, the subscription's `current_period_end` timestamp will be updated to the "current" period end. In that case the subscription's status will be updated to be `incomplete`: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#payment-status